# Forced to repeat variables in methods

Tags: reactjs

Everytime I define a handler method, I am forced to repeat variables even if two methods share the same ones. For instance:

```js
handleBreak(evt) {
  const id = evt.target.id;
  let breakVar = this.state.breakSession;
  let isPaused = this.state.isPaused;
  let breakBegan = this.state.breakBegan;
}

handleSession(evt) {
  const id = evt.target.id;
  let sessionVar = this.state.session;
  let isPaused = this.state.isPaused;
  let intervalBegan = this.state.intervalBegan;
  let breakBegins = document.getElementById('timer-label');
  let breakBegan = this.state.breakBegan;
}
```

Aside from creating a function that contains those same variables and passing the return to the handlers, is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the variable from `props` and `state` in each method is the desired way to work with variables in React. It makes the component test-friendly.

*Passing the variable between class methods is not recommended unless you're passing the event from an event listener.*

That being said, you can write access your variables from `state` and `props` in a more concise way without using the `.` operator.

#### Destructuring Assignment

This code

```
handleBreak(evt) {
  const id= evt.target.id;
  let breakVar= this.state.breakSession;
  let isPaused= this.state.isPaused;
  let breakBegan= this.state.breakBegan;
}

handleSession(evt) {
  const id= evt.target.id; 
  let sessionVar= this.state.session;
  let isPaused=this.state.isPaused;
  let intervalBegan=this.state.intervalBegan;
  let breakBegins=document.getElementById("timer-label");
  let breakBegan= this.state.breakBegan;
}
```

can be written as

```
handleBreak(evt) {
  const { target: { id } = {} } = evt;
  let { breakVar, isPaused, breakBegan } = state;
}

handleSession(evt) {
  const { target: { id } = {} } = evt;
  let { sessionVar, isPaused, intervalBegan, breakBegan } = this.state;      
  let breakBegins=document.getElementById("timer-label");
}
```

More on *Destructuring Assignment* here - [Destructuring Assignment MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. These methods aren´t really passing variables to each other, they are accesing variables from state to set up conditionals. If this isn´t the proper way, how would it be?

Comment: @HernanAriel What you're doing is right. I just put that note out as a general guideline for anyone visiting this post later. I have seen folks destructure all variables in one place and pass them between class methods. That is just a general note and nothing specifying to your approach. That's why I italicized it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ES6 Destructuring](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/) and do something like

```
const { session, isPaused, intervalBegan, breakBegan } = this.state;
```